# Minimizing android game

Tags: android

I am programming a game for android and lately I have found an issue when minimizing it. Basically the game won't stop when minimized and is still performing the code.

I override the onPause() and onResume().

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    ((com.anderiel.atomic.defense.AtomicDefense)MyCustomView).Pause();
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
     ((com.anderiel.atomic.defense.AtomicDefense)MyCustomView).Resume();
}
```

Adding them to the code that should stop the game code when it is paused. It works quite fine if i pause the game by myself (going to pause menu). But when I minimize it and then maximize it once again, no pause happens.

Comment: Could be wrong, but wouldn't you need to capture a reference to your `MyCustomView` when you create it and then call the `Pause()` function on that variable? `MyCustomView gameView = new MyCustomView();` followed by `gameView.Pause()`?

Comment: is MyCustomView a variable or a class name ? variables should start with lower case letters

Comment: its an instance of view in which my game is running, it is a private member of the activity and is inicialized in the onCreate method

Answer (score 0):

Does the game continue from the point where you turn off the screen? Or does it restart completely?
If the app restarts, try adding this to your manifest:

```
android:configChanges= "orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: You are answering a 6 year old question :D i really have no idea now, i dont even have the code anymore :D